# Excel: Using nested IF statements containing wildcard characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

I'm currently working on a project where I have a list of patient visits to a clinic. Each patient is assigned a Primary Care Provider, but that's not always the Rendering Provider at a given visit. My task is to see how many visits the clinic had where the patient actually saw their PCP. I actually solved that problem on this site a few days ago and was able to use an IF statement in Excel to determine all of that.

(Note: with the way the data gets pulled from the database, the PCP field contains the provider's full name and credentials while the Rendering field only contains the last name)

```
=IF(COUNTIF([@PCP],"*"&[@Rendering]&"*")>0,"YES","")
```

It works perfectly. The issue is that I've learned of a new twist: since the clinic's providers work in teams, a patient is said to have seen their PCP if they have their visit with anyone on that PCP's team. So I can no longer just compare the PCP and Rendering fields in my Excel list.

I know what needs to be done, but I'm not sure how to do it. All attempts so far have resulted in non-specific Excel syntax errors.

I'll try to set it up a little better for everyone. Let's say there are two teams of three providers.

```
Smith, John MD         Brown, Bob MD
Jones, Mike MD         Green, Ann MD
Doe, Jane MD           White, Mary MD
```

My table shows the Rendering and PCP names side by side, and I had wanted to add another column containing the IF statement that performs the check (probably something that just says "YES" for positive results and leaves everything else blank). It should look something like this:

```
Rendering              PCP                     Seen PCP/team?
---------------------------------------------------------------
Smith                  Smith, John MD          YES
Smith                  Jones, Mike MD          YES
Brown                  Smith, John MD
Green                  Brown, Bob MD           YES
Doe                    White, Mary MD
Doe                    Jones, Mike MD          YES
```

So the result should only be negative if the Rendering and PCP names are from different teams. And since I'm now checking against a *list* of names (or strings of text) rather than just doing a simple comparison between cells, I can't just use my `@PCP` and `@Rendering` parameters anymore (unless I'm totally missing something). I'm picturing a series of nested `IF` statements and have spent some time just sketching out the basic structure of what it will need to look like.

```
=IF(@PCP = Smith AND @Rendering = Smith, "YES", IF(@PCP = Smith AND @Rendering = Jones, "YES", IF(@PCP = Smith AND @Rendering = Doe, "YES", IF(@PCP = Jones AND @Rendering = Jones, "YES", IF(@PCP = Jones AND @Rendering = Smith, "YES", IF(@PCP = Jones AND @Rendering = Doe, "YES", IF(@PCP = Doe AND @Rendering = Doe, "YES", IF(@PCP = Doe AND @Rendering = Smith, "YES", IF(@PCP = Doe AND @Rendering = Jones, "YES", "")))))))))
```

Obviously that syntax isn't all correct, and that's only one of the two teams (I'm actually dealing with *four* teams in real life), but am I on the right track? I tried doing just a condensed version with only two providers just as an experiment and Excel just gave me the "It looks like you're trying to write a formula..." pop up and wouldn't tell me what was actually wrong. I know I'll need to make use of wildcard characters unless I want to type out the providers' full names for the PCP field...

Anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the list of visits on `Sheet1` and the list of teams are on `Sheet2`. I'd do (on `Sheet1 C2`):

`=IF(AND(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,"*"&A2&"*")>0,COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,B2)>0),"YES",IF(AND(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3,"*"&A2&"*")>0,COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3,B2)>0),"YES",""))`

Here is a sample of the file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0JhiS_KbIZSnlWSno4

Comment: I think this should end up working! I'll keep playing with it and come back to mark the answer if I'm satisfied with the results. Thanks for including the example file too -- that's super helpful

Comment: Update: this was exactly what I needed. I altered the formula to account for all four of our actual teams and it works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Team Name for example Team A (Smith, John MD and Jones, Mike MD and Doe, Jane MD) Team B (Brown, Bob MD and Green, Ann MD and White, Mary MD) you can add all your teams in 2 columns one for PCP the second Team Name (A, B, C and D) Use Vlookup to find the Team Name for each Rendering and PCP and compare it with If, when you have the same Team write YES else "" empty.

`=IF(VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",$F$2:$G$7,2,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$G$7,2,FALSE),"YES","")`

`=if(vlookup("*"&@Rendering&"*",PCP:Team,2,False)=vlookup(@PCP,PCP:Team,2,False),"YES","")`

Your Data is in A1:B7 as your second table (Rendering, PCP, Seen...)
F2:G7 is the array of the 2 columns (PCP:Team)
2 in Vlookup to read the second column Team Name
False to have the exact result

[image]